# How to run the Function Pass before the Module Pass in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I'm implementing several Passes on the LLVM in order to add original optimization,
These Passes are based on `FunctionPass` and `ModulePass`.
Now, each Pass is invoked by corresponding `opt` command option which is
registerd by `RegisterPass` template.

In future, I'd like to these Passes to be invoked only by one opt command option.
My idea is as follows:

- First, Function passes to run, and finally Module pass to run.
- Each Function passes to use the former Function passes' analysis information.
- The final Module pass to construct a new function using the former Function passes' result.
- All of these Passes sequence to invoke by only one opt command option specifying the final Module pass.

I thought I could make it with `addRequired` method in the `AnalysisUsage` class.
However, it doesn't seem to work:

- In the Function pass, several Function passes may be `addRequired` in the order.
- In the Function `pass`, only one Module pass may be addRequired.
- In the Function `pass(X)`, Function pass and Module pass cannot be `addRequired` simultaneously.
  i.e. `opt` command execution with option `X` causes to a lock status.
- In the Module pass, only one Module pass may be `addRequired`.
- In the Module `pass(Y)`, Function `pass(Z)` cannot be `addRequired`.
  i.e. `opt` command with option `Y` executes only `Y`, and Function `pass(Z)` is ignored.

I am not familiar to the Pass manager mechanism.
Anybody help me how to run the Function pass before the Module pass with only one `opt` command option?

---

The case of  execution is shown below:-

```sh
$ opt -stats -load ~/samples/tryPass4.so -MPass4 hello2.ll -S -o tryPass4.ll -debug-pass=Structure
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -datalayout -notti -basictti -x86tti -MPass4 -verify -verify-di -print-module
Target Library Information                                              ↑
Data Layout　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　-FPass4 doesn't appear here
No target information
Target independent code generator's TTI
X86 Target Transform Info
  ModulePass Manager
    Module Pass
      Unnamed pass: implement Pass::getPassName()
    FunctionPass Manager
      Module Verifier
    Debug Info Verifier
    Print module to stderr
Pass Arguments:  -FPass4　　　　<- here -FPass4 appears, but not executed
  FunctionPass Manager
    Function Pass


***** Module Name : hello2.ll  <- output from the Module pass
```

---

The source code for above is as follows:-

```cpp
using namespace llvm;
namespace{
 class tryFPass4 : public FunctionPass { 
   public :
    static char ID;
    tryFPass4() : FunctionPass(ID){}
    ~tryFPass4(){}
    virtual bool runOnFunction(llvm::Function &F);
    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(llvm::AnalysisUsage &AU) const;
 };
 class tryMPass4 : public ModulePass { 
   public :
    static char ID;
    tryMPass4() : ModulePass(ID){}
    ~tryMPass4(){}
    virtual bool runOnModule(llvm::Module &M);
    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(llvm::AnalysisUsage &AU) const;
 };
}
bool tryFPass4::runOnFunction(Function &F) {
  bool change = false;
   ....  
  return change;
}
bool tryMPass4::runOnModule(Module &M) {
  bool change = false ;
   ....
  return change;
}

void tryFPass4::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
  AU.setPreservesCFG(); 
}

void tryMPass4::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
  AU.setPreservesCFG();
  AU.addRequired<tryFPass4>();
}
char tryFPass4::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<tryFPass4> X("FPass4", "Function Pass", false, false);

char tryMPass4::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<tryMPass4> Y("MPass4", "Module Pass", false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate the problem [here](https://github.com/compor/usuterram/blob/master/llvm/dependencies-pass/pass/MyPasses.cpp) using LLVM 3.8.1.

I believe your `Function` pass gets to run here:

```
Module Pass
  Unnamed pass: implement Pass::getPassName()
```

I do not know why it is marked as unnamed although `getPassName` is overriden.

A fine detail that you need to watch is that in order for the function pass to actually execute its `runOnFunction` method, you need to invoke the `Function &` specific method of `getAnalysis` as in:

```
getAnalysis<tryFPass4>(f); // where f is the current Function operating on
```

It seems if the dependent pass operates on a small unit of IR than the pass that requires it, it needs to be executed explicitly. I might be mistaken since I have not yet tried it with a `BasicBlockPass` required by a `FunctionPass`.